# Creating dynamic insert form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic

Hi i have the code below:

```
<form method="post" action="catalog2.php">

    <div id="tabella" class="table-responsive">

        <script>
            var numrighe = prompt("Numero di prodotti da inserire", "Numero prodotti");

            alert("stampo " + numrighe);

            mytable ="<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">";
            mytable +="<thead>";
            mytable +="<tr><th>Cod</th><th>Description</th><th>Specifics</th></tr>";
            mytable +="</thead><tbody><tr>";

            for (var i = 0; i < numrighe; i++) 
            {
              if (i % 3 == 1 && i != 0) 
              {
                mytable += "</tr><tr>";
              }

              mytable += "<td><input type="text" maxlength=50 name="cod"" + i + " size=35></td>";
              mytable += "<td><input type="text" maxlength=100 name="desc"" + i + " size=30></td>";
              mytable += "<td><input type="text" maxlength=100 name="spec"" + i + " size=30>";

            }

            mytable +="</tr></tbody></table>";

            var div = document.getElementById('tabella');

            div.appendChild(mytable);

        </script>

    <center><input type="submit" value="Inserisci valori"></center>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to print a form table with a dynamic number of rows, to use in the next page with PHP code.

If I try to excute it with just only the first row, it will work. But if I add the rest of code it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving? On which line the error appears?

Comment: How do you create a second row?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this javascript code

```
<form method="post" action="catalog2.php">
    <div id="tabella" class="table-responsive">
        <script>
            var numrighe = prompt("Numero di prodotti da inserire", "Numero prodotti");
            alert("stampo " + numrighe);
            mytable = "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-hover table-striped\">";
            mytable += "<thead>";
            mytable += "<tr><th>Cod</th><th>Description</th><th>Specifics</th></tr>";
            mytable += "</thead><tbody><tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < numrighe; i++) {
                mytable += "<td><input type=\"text\" maxlength=50 name=\"cod\"" + i + " size=35></td>";
                mytable += "<td><input type=\"text\" maxlength=100 name=\"desc\"" + i + " size=30></td>";
                mytable += "<td><input type=\"text\" maxlength=100 name=\"spec\"" + i + " size=30>";
                if (i % 3 == 1 && i != 0) {
                    mytable += "</tr><tr>";
                }
            }
            mytable += "</tr></tbody></table>";
            var div = document.getElementById('tabella');
            div.innerHTML = mytable + div.innerHTML;
            //div.innerHTML is concatenated so that the old html is not lost.
        </script>
        <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Inserisci valori">
        </center>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. You can't do += to an DOM element. It's not a String. If you go by the javascript way, you would have to use document.createElement() method.

Comment: you can use it to create a DOM element  because at the end I added it to `div` as an HTML code by assigning it as the `innerHTML` of the div

Comment: If you do that the all tags in the div will be erased and this will also cause your script tag to be erased off the code.

Comment: I am telling you this because someone else might just come and down-vote. Read more about .innerHtml [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) . As it is mentioned, .innerHtml replaces and not adds. You'll have to use .appendChild()

Comment: This work fine! I copy and paste you code and it's working, the only difference with my code is 'div.InnerHTML' at the end. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between Javascript and jQuery. Edit the script tag to this :

```
   var mytable =$("<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">");
   mytable.html("<thead>");
   mytable.html(mytable.html()+"<tr><th>Cod</th><th>Description</th><th>Specifics</th></tr>");
   mytable.html(myTable.html()+"</thead><tbody><tr>");

   for (var i = 0; i < numrighe; i++) 
   {
     if (i % 3 == 1 && i != 0) 
        mytable.html(myTable.html()+"</tr><tr>");
     mytable.html(myTable.html()+"<td><input type="text" maxlength=50 name="cod"" + i + " size=35></td>");
     mytable.html(myTable.html()+"<td><input type="text" maxlength=100 name="desc"" + i + " size=30></td>");
     mytable.html(myTable.html()+"<td><input type="text" maxlength=100 name="spec"" + i + " size=30>");

   }

     mytable.html(myTable.html()+"</tr></tbody></table>");

     var div = document.getElementById('tabella');
     div.appendChild(mytable);
```

And don't forget to add jQuery in the head for this to work

Comment: I tried to modify the code, with yours but it doesn't work, i don't know why but thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you import Jquery?

Comment: Then it should definitely work. Please check for syntax errors.

Comment: The solution was that I have to build a string with the html code inside and then put it on the html() method. Thanks to all!